# JSF : Elements of ArrayList are not rendered properly?

Tags: java, jsf, data-structures, arraylist

I am trying to display elements of `arrayList` on `xhtml` page, but every time i upload new file then on status page i get multiple entries of last uploaded file rather then having details about all elements present in the array.

Here is the code

**XHTML Code:**

```
<ace:dataTable id ="archiveResults" resizableColumns="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" paginator="true" page="1" value="${fileUpload.resultBeanList}" var="result">
        <ace:column id="fileUploadFileName" headerText="uploaded file" sortBy="#{result.fileName}" filterBy="#{result.fileName}" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputFormat id="cellFileUploadFileName" value="${result.fileName}" />
        </ace:column>
        <ace:column id="fileUploadTime" headerText="time run" sortBy="#{result.timeRun}" filterBy="#{result.timeRun}" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputFormat id="cellFileUploadTime" value="${result.timeRun}" />
        </ace:column>
        <ace:column id="fileUploadJobType" headerText="job type" sortBy="#{result.jobType}" filterBy="#{result.jobType}" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputFormat id="cellFileUploadJobType" value="${result.jobType}" />
        </ace:column>
        <ace:column id="fileUploadStatus" headerText="Status" sortBy="#{result.status}" filterBy="#{result.status}" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputFormat id="cellFileUploadStatus" value="${result.status}" />
        </ace:column>
</ace:dataTable>
```

**Java Code:**

```
  private List<ResultBean> resultBeanList = new ArrayList<ResultBean>();
    private ResultBean resultBean = new ResultBean();

    public ResultBean getResultBean() {
        return resultBean;
    }

    public void setResultBean(ResultBean resultBean) {
        this.resultBean = resultBean;
    }

    public List<ResultBean> getResultBeanList() {
        System.out.println("resultBeanList: "+resultBeanList.toString());
        return resultBeanList;
    }

    public void setResultBeanList(List<ResultBean> resultBeanList) {
        this.resultBeanList = resultBeanList;
    }

public void uploadFile(FileEntryEvent event) {
        FileEntry fileEntry = (FileEntry) event.getSource();
        FileEntryResults results = fileEntry.getResults();
        FileEntry fe = (FileEntry) event.getComponent();
        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage();
        for (FileEntryResults.FileInfo fileInfo : results.getFiles()) {
            if (fileInfo.isSaved()) {
                File file = fileInfo.getFile();
                String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                resultBean.setStatus(fileInfo.getStatus().toString());
                resultBean.setFileName(fileInfo.getFileName());
                resultBean.setJobType(selectedItem);
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = new Date();
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
                resultBean.setTimeRun(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
            }
            resultBeanList.add(resultBean);
        }
    }
```

Comment: do your managed bean has ViewScope or RequestScope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are reusing your resultbean. You should create a new instance of `ResultBean` in your upload method, this should fix the problem.

Comment: No, it would not fix the issue as then how get getters be called?

Comment: maybe i didn't understood you clearing, what did you meant by creating new resultBean in upload Method

Comment: right "below public void uploadFile(FileEntryEvent event) {" add resultBean = new ResultBean()

Comment: it works now but i didn't understood the reason why, can you elaborate?

Comment: You were overwriting your old objects before. The list is just an object storer - it does not copy the object.

Comment: but if i check values present in the list then it did had all the data.